Is it possible to specify multiple annotations into the --test-targets command
According to the firebase documentation I should be able to specify multiple test target filters - https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/firebase/test/android/run#--test-targets
I've specified custom annotations like this
@Target(AnnotationTarget.FUNCTION)
@Retention(AnnotationRetention.RUNTIME)
annotation class MyAnnotationOne


@Target(AnnotationTarget.FUNCTION)
@Retention(AnnotationRetention.RUNTIME)
annotation class MyAnnotationTwo

And tagging my tests accordingly with @MyAnnotationOne @MyAnnotationTwo
When I run my firebase command with just one annotation it works
--test-targets="annotation com.foo.MyAnnotationOne" \

But when I try to specify multiple annotations, it does not work.
--test-targets="annotation com.foo.MyAnnotationOne,annotation com.foo.MyAnnotationTwo" \

Any ideas on how I can specify multiple annotations? Is it possible?
Tried the below and no tests ran
--test-targets="annotation com.foo.MyAnnotationOne,annotation com.foo.MyAnnotationTwo" \


According to AndroidJRunner documentation, you should remove the second annotation, like for instance:
--test-targets="annotation com.foo.MyAnnotationOne,com.foo.MyAnnotationTwo"

Hope this helps
